# How are ClickOnce Manifests built?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

My team is working on developing a new feature for an internal application.  We've branched the project and have been developing our feature.  Now I'm trying to deploy to a QA environment using Click Once.  When I try to install the application using the deployed Click Once install, I get this error:

> Unable to install or run the application. The application requires
>   that assembly Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.v15.2 Version
>   15.2.20152.1000 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.

When I open the .manifest file I can see why.  This assembly is listed as a prerequisite...

```
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite" allowDelayedBinding="true">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.v15.2" version="15.2.20152.1000" publicKeyToken="7DD5C3163F2CD0CB" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

And we don't want this assembly in the GAC.  (Note that the QA build of the application without our new feature works fine and does not have this dependency in the .manifest.)

So what I can't figure out is why it's listed as a prerequisite.  If I open the project properties and select the Publish tab, I can configure the Click Once deployment.  So I open the "Application Files" dialog and find the assembly.  The Publish Status is set to "Include" (and not to either "Prerequisite" nor to "Prerequisite (Auto)".)  So what I'm trying to figure out is why this is getting added to my manifest like this.

**Additional info**:  If I scroll down further in my .manifest file I also see this entry:

```
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.v15.2.dll" size="147456">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.v15.2" version="15.2.20152.2023" publicKeyToken="7DD5C3163F2CD0CB" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>9PKMWPyXwq1e6MjDM2jN++yzombFFoRA/GlyrvJTu00=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

Notice that this is a newer version of the same assembly.  And when I make changes to the "Application Files" section, I see them in this dependency tag, and not in the first dependency tag.  Any idea where this first dependency tag comes from?

Comment: It is surely located in the GAC on your machine so by default your project does not copy it into your Release build directory.  Select the assembly reference in your project's References node.  In the Properties window change the Copy Local property to *true*.  Rebuild the project and verify that it is now included in Publish > Application Files list and its Publish Status is "Include".

Comment: That doesn't seem to have had any impact.  The .manifest entries have not changed and I'm still getting the error message when I try to install from the ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: Pretty hard to believe that the manifest did not change when the Publish Status is so different.  Well, use Infragistics support, ask them for the correct CO deployment procedure for their product.

Comment: To be clear, these two dependency sections did not change.  I did not compare the rest of the manifest.  I'm sorry that it's difficult to believe, but it's the truth.  (I even cleaned and rebuilt the solution after setting the "Copy Local" property to True.)

Comment: If anyone has a link to a good document, I'd appreciate it.  None of the articles that I've seen so far were helpful.